# Add button "More" to show another button on UITabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I want to show more 2 "button" when touch in a tab on "UITabbarController", how can I do that.
I use UIActionSheet but when I call

```
[choiceSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
[choiceSheet showFromTabBar:[[self tabBarController] tabBar]];
```

it show `UIActionSheet` but still catch excepton.

Comment: Please describe it again and show some code and also note what exception you get and when you get it

Answer (score 1):

As soon as there are more than 5 viewControllers inside a tabbarcontroller, the fifth entry becomes 'More...' and a list of the remaining view controllers is shown

**This is the intrinsic behaviour of the UITabbarController**

Comment: I don't see that, I user UITabbarController.

Comment: Please shpw us your code / story board / xib layout - edit your question

Comment: When touch "More" button on tab bar, I want to show 2 more button